# go run command not providing enough information to debug

Tags: go

when I was trying out scenarios on channels in go, I came across a code to reproduce deadlock as below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)
    c <- true
}
```

when I run it using

> go run gorouting.go

I am getting the below output

```
> main.main()
>         E:/GO Samples/gorouting.go:13 +0x57 
> exit status 2
```

but when I did run in https://play.golang.org I got more details about the exception, am I missing something in the command or do i need to do any configuration at the machine level?

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

    goroutine 1 [chan send]:
    main.main()
        /tmp/sandbox592049259/main.go:7 +0x60
```

I am running with this configuration

> go version go1.10.3 windows/amd64

Thanks for the help

Comment: Is your go environment set up correctly? It might seem that the included code is not the code being run. The included code does not have a line 13.

Comment: i have trimmed some unreachable code,I am not sure abt environment but programs are compiled and giving o/p as expected

Comment: Then a) your environment is ill configured and `go run gorouting` is compiling/executing the wrong file, or b) the included code does not reflect the contents of `E:/GO Samples/gorouting.go`. I suggest you copy `E:/GO Samples/gorouting.go` in its entirety into your question.

Comment: Please provide the shortest, actual Go source that produces your output.

Comment: above mentioned code is the complete code

Answer (score 0):

When you use `go run xxx.go` go only compiles/runs that file within the main package...versus running `go install && xxx` where xxx is the name of your executable.  `go install` builds everything and copies to the bin dir...try that locally.